# unattractive additive effect to opacity with pstricks

Tags: pstricks, transparency, pst-node

I'm using `pstricks` to highlight by boxing or circling replacement text in my math equations.  But, I don't want this highlighting to occlude what's behind it.  So, I've been setting `opacity` or `strokeopacity` to accomplish this.  Everything seemed to be working as I wanted it to until I started trying to connect the nodes.  Then where the arrows and connects and boxes overlapped, I got annoying additive side effects from the opacity.  What really surprised me was to learn that arrows and their lines are treated as two separated objects by `pstricks`.

Anyway, does anyone know a way around this?  I'm open to any suggestions.  I know pratically nothing about `tikz`: really only enough to make myself constantly frustrated.  Nevertheless, I am open to `tikz` solutions too.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\myboxn}[3][red!60]{%
            \rnode{#2}{\psframebox[boxsep=false,
                                   framesep=0.5pt,
                                   linewidth=3pt,
                                   strokeopacity=0.4,
                                   linecolor=#1]{#3}}}
    \begin{align*}
         \sqrt{2} - 1   & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}                                   \\[2ex]
         \sqrt{2} - 1   & = \dfrac{1}{2 + \myboxn{A}{\sqrt{2}-1}}                  \\[2ex]
         \sqrt{2} - 1   & = \dfrac{1}{2 + \myboxn{B}{\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}-1}}}    
    \end{align*}

    \ncline[arrows=-D>,
            linecolor=red,
            linewidth=3pt,
            arrowscale=1.25,
            strokeopacity=.40]{A}{B}


\end{document}
```

By the way, I know I can set the *parameters* using `\psset{...}` but in the actually document, there is a lot going on with different different styles.  So, I'd prefer to stick to passing the parameters individually to `\ncline` etc.

[image]

Comment: A `pstricks` solution would definitely be my preference. At least that way I would learn it better.

Comment: I will offer a bounty of 500! (not 500 factorial).

Comment: create an arrow which doesn't overlap with the line end.

Comment: @Herbert but it's not just the arrow heads.  There seem to be a lot of small parts overlapping---even with just the boxes.

Comment: @A.Ellett: that is a problem with your viewer. I cannot see it with Okular 0.15.5 under Linux

Comment: @Herbert But I also see it in the image I've posted here.

Comment: I see it with both Mac OS X's previewer and Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @A.Ellett: see my example output

Answer (score 3):

use `arrowinset=0,` in the settings:

[image]

Comment: I still see overlapping pieces with an additive effect to the hue.

Comment: OK.  So the rectangles are better.  That had to have been a LaTeX issue (I updated LaTeX between now and when I originally posted this question).  But that still leaves a question about how to find the arrow.

Comment: @A.Ellett: I'll have a look at weekend to create another arrow.

Comment: @A.Ellett: already done, I forgot about the `arrowinset` option. see new image

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  But the problem with that approach is that I'll have inconsistent arrows---however, that's just a minor complaint.  Still, how to correct the overlapping with the squares remains.

Comment: @A.Ellett: as I already wrote, it is _not_ a PSTricks problem.

Comment: and you can set globally `\psset{arrowinset=0}` to get always the same style.